# CVE-2016-3710 mitigation in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, kvm-virtualization

I have a box running Ubuntu 15.04 for KVM virtualization purposes.

As I [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases), it has run out of support since 04.02.2016.

Does it means there would be no official [packet updates for mitigating CVE-2016-3710](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-3710.html) for this OS? If the answer is "yes", so how could I mitigate CVE-2016-3710 in my system? Upgrading to 16.04 release is the only way for me?

Answer (score 1):

If support is ending for it, I would suggest compiling qemu yourself. This way as soon as patches are fixed upstream, you can recompile the newly patched versions and not worry about waiting for maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on this chart: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases , support for Ubuntu 15.04 ended in February 2016. This means none of the packages for 15.04 will receive updates of any kind, including security updates. Current and future security risks will not be patched, so it is highly recommended to switch to a supported version. You are welcome to try to apply security fixes on your own by recompiling software, installing unofficial versions, or backporting packages from newer Ubuntu versions -- it's your system -- but this is completely unsupported and any breakage is at your own risk.

For future reference, if you plan on sticking with a specific version of Ubuntu for a long time without upgrading, it's best to stay with LTS, or Long-Term-Support releases, which receive security updates for 5 years from the date of release. Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 are Long Term Support releases.